# How do I Activate a project in a BLC extension?

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a project record in a BLC extension - and I'm trying to Activate it after a save - but in looking through the source code, it's a protected method that's inaccessible and can't be executed:

```
public PXAction<PMProject> activate;
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true), PXUIField(DisplayName = "Activate Project")]
protected virtual IEnumerable Activate(PXAdapter adapter) => adapter.Get();
```

This code snippet also tells me nothing about what's actually occurring in that method - where's the body?

So - bottom line:  How do I activate the project through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as setting the current project record to your project and pressing the Activate action from the code like below

```
ProjectEntry projectEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
/*
 * Configure your current project record here
 */
projectEntry.activate.PressButton();// this line will run te Activate action
/*
 * Do the remaining required actions/changes
 */
```